# parallel RLC circuit / short out?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, passive-networks

The problem said the resistor 300ohms is short out by the switch when t>0s 
why can this resistor be short out?
useless condition or others condition?
[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. How can the resistor be shorted out? By closing the switch to connect it's terminal directly to the negative terminal of the source.

Comment: By closing the switch. Whether you do that by pushing a button or moving a lever doesn't matter.

Comment: It says that the 150V source AND 300 ohm resistor are shorted.

Comment: You could draw in the source and resistor like you started to do in your right side diagram. Then solve the whole circuit, and what you'll find is that the source and resistor don't affect the rest of the circuit.

Comment: ok finally i know

Answer (score 1):

This is a homework problem / thought experiment.  This is neither a useful nor a useless condition - it is simply a setup used to create a problem.  It may or may not ever correspond to a real life situation.  So, "how this happens" is irrelevant - all you need to know is that at t=0 the circuit transforms from (a) to (b).

To solve this problem, use the following steps:

1) Solve the steady state solution for circuit (a) on the left.  Specifically, you need the inductor current and capacitor voltage.

2) At t = 0, the switch closes, which turns the circuit into circuit (b) on the right.

3) Since you know the initial conditions for the inductor and capacitor, you can now find vc(t) for the circuit on the right to complete the problem.

Comment: This is exactly how we need answer problems relating to homework on this website. +1, nice work.

Comment: Thank you!  I figured there were several reasons not to give the complete answer - chief among them, that sounded like way too much work ;)

Comment: You're welcome! The point of this website is to provide guidance and not an answer, which is exactly what you did. If this website relied on giving answers, you can imagine the amount of college (and sometimes high school) students that would be considered cheaters.